# Как в AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle работать с переменными

Tags: php, symfony2, yml

Суть проблемы заключается в следующем. У меня есть проект на symfony 2.3 в котором используется бандо [symfony2admingenerator](http://symfony2admingenerator.org). Этот модуль отвечает за построения журналов и за действия с ними.

Проблема заключается в том, что на определённое действие я не могу правильно настроить не стандартный маршрут. Сам маршрут имеет следующий формат: `@Route("/{id}/equipment-bind", name="Nitra_OutletBundle_BindPosEquipment")`

Описание журналов ведётся в формате yml. Ниже полное описание справочника.

```
generator: admingenerator.generator.doctrine
params:
model:            Nitra\SchemaCDBBundle\Entity\POS
namespace_prefix: Nitra
bundle_name:      OutletBundle
fields:
  id:
    dbType: string
    label:  fields.pos.id
  custId:
    label:  fields.pos.custId
  kodPos:
    label:  fields.pos.kodPos
  name: 
    label:  fields.pos.name
  address:  
    label:  fields.pos.address
  legalName:  
    label:  fields.pos.legalName
  legalAddress: 
    label:  fields.pos.legalAddress
  latitude:   
    label:  fields.pos.latitude
  longitude:      
    label:  fields.pos.longitude
  timeWorkFrom:        
    label:  fields.pos.timeWorkFrom
  timeWorkTo: 
    label:  fields.pos.timeWorkTo
  timeBreakFrom:
    label:  fields.pos.timeBreakFrom
  timeBreakTo:
    label:  fields.pos.timeBreakTo
  phone: 
    label:  fields.pos.phone
  fax:     
    label:  fields.pos.fax
  edrpou: 
    label:  fields.pos.edrpou
  description:  
    label:  fields.pos.description
  numberOfCells: 
    label:  fields.pos.numberOfCells
  lengthShelf: 
    label:  fields.pos.lengthShelf          
  salesSquare:    
    label:  fields.pos.salesSquare
  whSquare:     
    label:  fields.pos.whSquare
  bStandart:     
    label:  fields.pos.bStandart
  daysOfCredit:  
    label:  fields.pos.daysOfCredit
  filial:  
    label:  fields.pos.filial
    sort_on: filial.translations.name
  posType:  
    label:  fields.pos.posType
    addFormOptions:
      group_by:  posTypeGroup.name
    sort_on: posType.translations.name
  posStatus:
    label:  fields.pos.posStatus
    sort_on: posStatus.translations.name
  network:  
    label:  fields.pos.network
    formType: select2_entity
    addFormOptions:
      group_by:    networkType.name
      configs:
        placeholder:  ''
    sort_on: network.translations.name
  settlement: 
    label:  fields.pos.settlement
    sort_on: settlement.translations.name
  employee:  
    label:  fields.pos.employee
    formType: select2_entity
    sort_on: employee.sureName
    addFormOptions:
      property:  formName
      configs:
        placeholder:  ''
  decisionMakers:   
    label:  fields.pos.decisionMakers
  visits:     
    label:  fields.pos.visits
  routeDetails:  
    label:  fields.pos.routeDetails
  tasks:
    label:  fields.pos.tasks
  morningMeetingDetails:  
    label:  fields.pos.morningMeetingDetails
  equipmentHeads: 
    label:  fields.pos.equipmentHeads
  debtHeads:  
    label:  fields.pos.debtHeads
  paymentHeads: 
    label:  fields.pos.paymentHeads
  saleHeads:  
    label:  fields.pos.saleHeads
  rtiKey:  
    label:  fields.pos.rtiKey
  priceHeads:  
    label:  fields.pos.priceHeads
  leftovers:
    label:   fields.pos.leftovers
  supervizor:
    label:   fields.pos.supervizor
    getter:  Employee.parent
  distributor:
    label:  fields.pos.distributor
    getter: filial.distributor
    dbType: string
  createdAt:  
    label:  fields.pos.createdAt
  updatedAt: 
    label:  fields.pos.updatedAt
  parent:
    label:    fields.pos.supervizor
    dbType:   string
    formType: text

object_actions:
  delete: 
    credentials: 'hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") or(hasRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN") or hasRole("ROLE_POS_EDIT"))'
  info:  
     label: action.object.posInfo
  editEquipment:
     label: action.object.editEquipment

builders:
list:
    params:
        max_per_page: 100
        title: list.title.pos
        display: [ custId, rtiKey, name, address, settlement, employee,     network, posType, posStatus ]
        actions:
            new:  ~
        object_actions: 
            info: ~
            edit: ~
            editEquipment: 
              route: Nitra_OutletBundle_BindPosEquipment
              params:
                id:  id

filters:
    params:
        display: [ custId, name, address, settlement, posType, rtiKey, network, posStatus, parent, employee, filial ]

new:
    params:
        credentials: 'hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") or(hasRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN") or hasRole("ROLE_POS_NEW"))'
        fields:
          id:
            addFormOptions:
              attr:
                 readonly: true
          custId:
            addFormOptions:
              attr:
                 readonly: true
          rtiKey:
            addFormOptions:
              attr:
                 readonly: true
        title: new.title.pos|{ POS.Name }|
        display: 
                "tab.pos.general":    [ rtiKey, id, custId, employee, posStatus ]
                "tab.pos.additional": [ name, address, posType, network ]
                "tab.pos.address":    [ settlement, latitude, longitude ]
                "tab.pos.legal":      [ legalName, edrpou, legalAddress ]
                "tab.pos.size":       [ timeWorkFrom, timeWorkTo, timeBreakFrom, timeBreakTo, numberOfCells, lengthShelf, salesSquare, whSquare, bStandart ]
                "tab.pos.contacts":   []
                "tab.pos.route_map":  []
                "tab.pos.order":      []
                "tab.pos.payment":    []



        actions:
            save: ~
            list: ~
            save-and-list:  ~
new:
    params:
        credentials: 'hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") or(hasRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN") or hasRole("ROLE_POS_NEW"))'
        title: edit.title.pos|{ POS.Name }|
        actions:
            save: ~
            list: ~
            save-and-list:  ~


edit:
    params:
        credentials: 'hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") or(hasRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN") or hasRole("ROLE_POS_EDIT"))'
        fields:
          id:
            addFormOptions:
              attr:
                 readonly: true
          custId:
            addFormOptions:
              attr:
                 readonly: true
          rtiKey:
            addFormOptions:
              attr:
                 readonly: true
        title: edit.title.pos|{ POS.Name }|
        display: 
                "tab.pos.general":    [ rtiKey, id, custId, employee, posStatus ]
                "tab.pos.additional": [ name, address, posType, network ]
                "tab.pos.address":    [ settlement, latitude, longitude ]
                "tab.pos.legal":      [ legalName, edrpou, legalAddress ]
                "tab.pos.size":       [ timeWorkFrom, timeWorkTo, timeBreakFrom, timeBreakTo, numberOfCells, lengthShelf, salesSquare, whSquare, bStandart ]
                "tab.pos.contacts":   []
                "tab.pos.route_map":  []
                "tab.pos.order":      []
                "tab.pos.payment":    []



        actions:
            save: ~
            list: ~
            save-and-list:  ~


show:
    params:
        title:    "You're viewing the object \"%object%\"|{ %object%: YourModel.title }|"
        display:  ~
                  #[ name ]
        actions:
            list: ~
            new:  ~
actions:
    params:
        object_actions:
            delete: ~
```

Мне нужно что бы когда отрабатывало действе `editEquipment:` подставлялись правильные значения в маршрут в частности ID объекта.

```
builders:
list:
    params:
        max_per_page: 100
        title: list.title.pos
        display: [ custId, rtiKey, name, address, settlement, employee, network, posType, posStatus ]
        actions:
            new:  ~
        object_actions: 
            info: ~
            edit: ~
            editEquipment: 
              route: Nitra_OutletBundle_BindPosEquipment
              params:
                id:  \"%POS%\"|{ %id%: POS.Id }|"
```

В [документации](http://symfony2admingenerator.org/documentation/form.html#overview)  вроде как просто но у меня не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался. Что бы генератор подставлял значения из схемы их нужно указывать в следующем формате `"{{ POS.id }}"`. Больше документации по данному банду можно посмотреть на [GIT](https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/documentation.md#table-of-contents).